# Quarkus outbox pattern with Debezium: how to add a custom column to outbox table

Tags: java, configuration, quarkus, debezium, outbox-pattern

I am using Debezium for implementing outbox pattern on Quarkus (v 2.3.0 Final) and it works fine!
I added a custom string column to my outbox table (on a Postgres DB) but when I call `event.fire`, the string value is not persisted.
I have found this property `table.fields.additional.placement` in Debezium configuration but I can not understand how to use it in Quarkus application.properties.
Is there anyone able to help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `table.fields.additional.placement` is used for configuring the event routing SMT, it's *not* an option of the Quarkus outbox extension. It looks indeed as if you cannot have additional columns in your outbox table when using that extension currently. I have logged this request via [DBZ-4317](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-4317). Any feedback and contributions for implementing this will be very welcomed.